# How to \let an xparse defined command?

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, xparse

Let `\example` be an `xparse` defined command, which takes one optional and one mandatory argument.  The definition of `\example` cannot be modified (e.g. because it comes from a third-party package).

The auhtor of `\example` forgot to handle an empty optional argument, so I want to patch it for my own use.  The TeX-way would be to `\let` the original definition of `\example` to something else and use this backup in the redefinition.

This is not possible with LaTeX macros, which take an optional argument (but Heiko made [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) for that).  Also, this is not possible for `xparse` defined macros, because `xparse` wraps the actual definition into some very smart argument parser construct.

I made the following *not* working example, where I naively used `\cs_new_eq:NN`, which makes TeX go into an infinite loop (because `\example` is now calling itself recursively in the `xparse` logic).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
 {
  #1 ~ #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\example[First]{Second}

\example{Second}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% This is obviously wrong
\cs_new_eq:NN \orig_example:wn \example

\RenewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
 {
  \IfValueTF { #1 }
   { \orig_example:wn [ #1 ] { #2 } }
   { \orig_example:wn { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\example[First]{Second}

\example{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: _Do not do this_: all `xparse`-defined commands should be interfaces to documented code-level functions. Thus if you need a different interface the correct way is to define a new command from scratch. We are of course still working on getting everything working this way!

Comment: @JosephWright I have a counter example there: `siunitx`.  The `\SI` macro for instance calls to `\__siunitx_…` functions.

Comment: I wrote `siunitx` v2 before we'd got all of the `xparse` stuff revised (and indeed part of the point of writing `siunitx` in `expl3` was to push development of the latter). I'm well-aware that it needs revising to have defined interfaces, and the development version (https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/tree/master) is going that way. (It's hard work as there are many things I would probably not do, with hindsight, but can't break existing documents.)

Comment: (ctd.) Thus _at present_ for `siunitx` you would have to model new interfaces using 'internal' code functions (regrettably). However, I assume the question is general and we are aiming at best-practice (which is _still developing).

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I'm looking for best practices there.  Perhaps this can also be seen as a feature request for `\LetDocumentCommand` in `xparse`, but I became aware of that when I wanted to overwrite `\num` from `siunitx`.

Comment: The problem is very similar to the one addressed by `letltxmacro` (which *cannot* be used here, though).

Comment: @HenriMenke As I say, we will _not_ add `\LetDocumentCommand` as it misses the _entire point_ of `xparse`. I'll add an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general the answer is *do not do this*. The idea behind `xparse` is the document level commands (`\example`) are there to define the syntax but should be implemented by use of documented code-level functions (so something like `\module_command:nn` here). As such, any new or altered definitions should *not* pass 'document level' syntax around at all but should be defined using `xparse` and the code-level functions the original uses

```
\NewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
  {
    \module_command:nn {#1} {#2} % Oops, doesn't cover \NoValue
  }
...
\RenewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \module_command:n {#2} } % Presumably different
      { \module_command:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
```

As such, the team quite deliberately don't provide `\LetDocumentCommand` or similar.

---

The best practice for `expl3` and `xparse` use has developed over some time and as such some packages written by the team themselves still need revision to follow them. From my own code, [`notes2bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) is probably the 'model' package in terms of showing the correct approach. On the other hand, at the time of writing the release version of [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) needs revision to follow them: the code was largely written in parallel with `expl3` and `xparse` development. There is [development ongoing](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/tree/master) to create a third version of `siunitx` which will be implemented with this clear separation. (I hope to get this ready during 2016.)

If you need to create a new interface for an `xparse`-defined command and it is built on non-documented code functions, at present you will have to use those

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
  {
    % To be revised once documented interfaces are available
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \__module_command:n {#2} } % Presumably different
      { \__module_command:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
```

Most authors making use of `expl3` are aware of this aim, but you might wish to check with them that such developments are ongoing.

Comment: Is there any guidance in the L3 docs concerning naming the highest level internal commands called by a document level command with a given name? Aside from more typing, one thing I don't like about this 'split' (but probably just my ignorance) is that it makes code more opaque i.e. it is harder to find what a command is doing in the source because you have an extra step involved in tracing it. But if the highest level internal commands followed some kind of consistent naming linking them to the document level commands, this would be a lot clearer from a user's point of view.

Comment: Good luck getting people to actually follow this....

Comment: What I don't understand is *why* I should separate these. It just seems to mean more work.... And I don't really know, either, what counts as too much mixing up and what doesn't since there has to be some mixing up. Or, at least, there seems to be. (But there's also stuff which there isn't expl3 syntax for, I think, and where should that be?) I think I just don't get the idea. Or the motivation. Or something.

Answer (score 13):

Commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` behave in an indirect way; the situation is similar to the one addressed by `letltxmacro` when dealing with commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, which is easier to describe.

When you do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{...#1...}
```

LaTeX actually defines *two* macros, in a way that's essentially

```
\edef\foo{\noexpand\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname foo \endcsname}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo \endcsname[1]{...#1...}
```

Note the trailing space in the name of the macro that does the real job. So, if you naively do

```
\let\origfoo\foo
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{\origfoo{#1}?}
```

the call `\foo{x}` in normal text, where `\protect` is `\relax`, would give, in succession, (using `•` to denote the trailing space in macro names having it)

```
\protect\foo•{x}          % first level expansion
\foo•{x}                  % \relax disappears
\origfoo{x}?              % replacement text of redefined \foo•
\protect\foo•{x}?         % first level expansion of \origfoo
\foo•{x}?                 % \relax disappears
```

Yikes! Infinite loop!

If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \example { o m }
 {
  #1 ~ #2
 }

\cs_show:N \example
```

the terminal output would be (reformatted for better reading)

```
> \example=\protected macro:->\int_zero:N \l__xparse_processor_int
    \tl_set:Nn \l__xparse_args_tl {\example code }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__xparse_fn_tl {\example }
    \__xparse_grab_D:w []{-NoValue-}
    \__xparse_grab_m_1:w \l__xparse_args_tl .
```

So when you do `\let\origexample\example` you just make it the same as this macro, but a subsequent

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\example}{...}{...}
```

would *change* the meaning of `\example` *and* of `\example•code` (again with a space in the name) which is actually the macro doing the real work. The same kind of infinite loop would arise, because the newly defined `\example•code` macro will contain a call of `\origexample` that will eventually call `\example•code`. Infinite loop.

Building `\LetDocumentCommand` is not conceptually difficult, nor it is adding such commands to the ones managed by `xpatch` or `regexpatch`, since they follow a common pattern just like `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

However the situation is *very* different: the main reason is that the way macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` work is not cast in stone. It could change abruptly if the team decides so: the usage of “private” functions with `__` in their name means exactly that no package developer should rely on this particular implementation.

The situation with `\DeclareRobustCommand` is different, because the LaTeX2e kernel publishes the interface (and indeed some packages exploiting this exist, not only `letltxmacro` and `xpatch`).

The reasons why `\LetDocumentCommand` will not be provided by `xparse` have been explained by Joseph Wright. You now have the tools for managing it, if you dare. I won't. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

While the warnings of Joseph Wright and egreg that one *shouldn't* do this may be just as valid today (or may not be; I don't know), it seems that things may have changed in the almost five years since the previous two answers.
In [*LaTeX News*, issue 32](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf), dated October 2020, on page 4, I note the following section (emphasis mine):

> #### Provide a way to copy robust commands. . .
>
> With the previous LaTeX2ε release, several user-level
> commands were made robust, so the need for a way
> to create copies of these commands (often to redefine
> them) increased, and the LaTeX2ε kernel didn’t have a
> way to do so. Previously this functionality was provided
> in part by Heiko Oberdiek’s letltxmacro package, which
> allows a robust command `\foo` to be copied to `\bar`
> with `\LetLtxMacro\bar\foo`.
>
> From this release onwards, the LaTeX2ε kernel
> provides `\NewCommandCopy` (and `\Renew...` and
> `\Declare...` variants) which functions almost like
> `\LetLtxMacro`. To the end user, both should work the
> same way, and one shouldn’t need to worry about the
> definition of the command: `\NewCommandCopy` should do
> the hard work.
>
> `\NewCommandCopy` knows about the different types of
> definitions from the LaTeX2ε kernel, and also from other
> packages, such as **xparse’s command declarations like
> `\NewDocumentCommand`**, and etoolbox’s `\newrobustcmd`,
> and it can be extended to cover further packages.
>
> [(github issue 239)](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/239)

Unfortunately, I don't have a sufficiently cutting-edge installation of LaTeX at hand to test out this `\NewCommandCopy` (or `\RenewCommandCopy`, I suppose) to provide an example of its use.

Comment: `\NewCommandCopy` still doesn't work on `xparse`-defined commands.  I have still to implement that (hopefully in the near future).  I opened an issue in the `latex3` repository to track that: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/795