# sanitize numbers with commas for \fpeval

Tags: siunitx, expl3

`\fpeval` doesn't like decimal numbers with commas as separator:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}
\sisetup{locale=DE}

\begin{document}
\num{1.5}
\num{1,5}
\num{\fpeval{1.5+1.4 + max(1.5 , 2 )}} 
\num{\fpeval{1,5+1,4 + max(1,5 , 2 )}} %error
\num{\fpeval{1,5+1.4}} %error

\end{document}
```

This gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Unexpected comma: extra arguments ignored.
```

As a german I'm rather used to commas (and other germans too) and so I constantly have to correct my input. Is there an *expandable* way to get this working?

The difficulty is naturally that the comma is used in the `\fpeval` syntax, e.g. for max. I would accept the requirement to use spaces here, or to use another symbol e.g. `;`, or to use some protection command like `\dontsanitize{max(1.5,2)}`, or `max(1,5 \realcomma 2)`.

Comment: The simpler approach would be to use `\sanitize{1,5}`. In any case I really don't understand the use of commas, I understand that one wants the output to be a comma (that's okey) but in the input, I think it's absolutely better to use a dot. Other programming languages use that, plus there's no doubt of what you wrote in `max(1,5,2)` (which is what is read inside `\ExplSyntax(On|Off)`). In any case, may be it could be changed the syntax to `max(1,2;2)` but I don't know the internals.

Comment: @Manuel I guess you aren't german ;-). When you are used to write decimals with commas since you were a child, it is not easy to always avoid that you do it also when you type. Beside this: due to my locale most applications (e.g. the windows calculator or my spreadsheet) copy  & paste numbers with commas.

Comment: Using spaces around nondecimal commas is out of the question, I'm afraid. It *may* be possible to make the `fp` module use either commas or periods for the decimal separator and a semicolon for separating arguments, but I wouldn't dare asking Bruno to implement it. Having a standard syntax for numeric fp expressions is much better.

Comment: @egreg: Even if it were possible I don't think that it would be a good idea to add it to `fp` directly. I would prefer an (expandable) command that I can inject if needed (and it would be okay if replace all commas by dots, the max-case seldom occur in the wild ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the `,digit` by `.digit` using l3regex

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}
\usepackage{l3regex}%unless you have very new expl3
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\let\oldnum\num
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\num#1{\def\tmp{#1}\regex_replace_all:nnN{,([0-9])}{.\1}{\tmp}\oldnum{\tmp}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\num{1.5}
\num{1,5}
\num{\fpeval{1.5+1.4 + max(1.5 , 2 )}} 
\num{\fpeval{1,5+1,4 + max(1,5 , 2 )}} %error
\num{\fpeval{1,5+1.4}} %error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\regex_replace_all:nnN` expandable? And I wonder what @JosephWright will say about the redefinition of \num ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, that's why I had to pull the redefinition up to the top level. I'm sure Joseph will be impressed by my adoption of expl3 syntax in the answer:-)

Comment: I think Joseph will be even more impressed when he sees how you expand the answer to S-columns ;-).

Comment: Related: [How to \let an xparse defined command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285551).